# CNN model on Rapberry Pi

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, raspberry-pi, keras

I am working on a project that involves glaucoma detection on the Raspberry pi 3B. The model was trained on my laptop and is around 400mb ".h5" file. I am trying to load the model onto the pi using keras The pi seems to load other smaller models but is showing up this error with mine:

```
2018-05-15 18:07:04.117054: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 134217728 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2018-05-15 18:07:05.052281: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 134217728 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2018-05-15 18:07:05.513437: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 134217728 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2018-05-15 18:07:06.191609: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 134217728 exceeds 10% of system memory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Could not allocate ndarray

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 273, in load_model
    topology.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f['model_weights'], model.layers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 3393, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
    K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2377, in batch_set_value
    get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Could not allocate ndarray
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This seems like a memory error, too many parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a large enough model, and eventually it won't fit on a 1Gb Pi. You're there.

You have three options:

1. Build a smaller model, or
2. See if there are non-essential services you can turn off (e.g., if you aren't running with a monitor, try the server install of Raspian), or
3. Upgrade to something with more RAM. E.g., the Asus Tinker or Oroid-2 boards, which are the same size as a Pi, but have 2Gb of RAM.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will be sure to try these.